# Pulling from two databases, three different tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need some guidance on how to pull data from two databases (same server), three different tables.  The two databases are [IDEAUrlBot] and [dbIdWhseLC].  The three tables are tbl_IDWItems(IDEAUrlBot), tbl_URLs(IDEAUrlBot), and tbItemTxt(dbIdWhseLC).

The columns I'm looking to pull are nIdPub(tbItemTxt), nItemId(tbl_IDWItems,tbItemTxt), UrlId(tbl_IDWItems,tbl_URLs) sTxt(tbItemTxt), UrlId(tbl_IDWItems,tbl_URLs) vUpdatedt(tbItemTxt). nItemId is the key column.

There will need to be a join with tbItemTxt.nItemId = tbl_IDWItems.  There will need to be a join on tbl_IDWItems.UrlId = tbl_URLs.UrlId as well.

I'm struggling with the separate database aspect of the query.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use the 3 part naming conventions `[database_name].[schema_name].[object_name]` See here for further information http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply use the full identifier of the table DataBase.dbo.Table

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the database name in front of the schema.tablename.

```
dbIdWhseLC.dbo.tbItemTxt
```